# Select Query Gives Unwanted Data

Tags: ms-access

I have a form (single form view) “frmInvoiceClient” which holds various information on invoices sent, or to be sent, to clients. One piece of information is the invoice foreign key.

An invoice lists a number of items which add up to the total invoice. I need to add the invoice foreign key to each item.

As a first step I tried to extract the invoice foreign key from frmInvoiceClient. This is my SQL:

```
SELECT tblInvoices.InvoicePK, tblInvoices.ClientFK
FROM tblInvoices
WHERE (((tblInvoices.ClientFK)=[Forms]![frmInvoiceClient]![ClientFK]));
```

When this query fires, only one record is showing on the form *frmInvoiceClient* but the query gives results for *all* invoices for that client.

How can I make the query show the result for only the record shown on frmInvoiceClient?

Comment: You'll need something that uniquely identifies the invoice like an invoice id, invoice number.

Comment: And where/how do you intend to use this query?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "when the query fires"? Are you opening another form?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but it's just dawned on me why this happens. I need to rethink. Perhaps a DLAST function that gives the invoice primary key that I've just made and update the Item with this. Thas plus some safeguards that prevent DLAST from being used to update items that shouldn't be updated.